# How do I solve issues in flutter doctor?

Tags: android-studio

I am downloading android studio in linux. When I run Flutter doctor, it results in the following:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 3.4.0-17.2.pre, on Ubuntu 23.04 6.2.0-39-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ android-studio-dir = /snap/android-studio
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I tried changing android studio directory, but still the problem persists.